# Is there a term for properties that an entity has at a particular time, but which depend on the properties it has at other times?

Tags: metaphysics, terminology, time, properties

Is there a term for properties that an entity has at a particular time, but which depend on the properties it has at other times?

For example, when he was a child, Lebron James had the property of being a future NBA player. This property depended on him possessing the property of being an NBA player at a future time. Or if the velocity of an object at a time t is the derivative of its position with respect to time at t, then the velocity of an object at t depends on its position at prior times.

Comment: Actually, in physics, velocity is considered part of the state at the current time. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics : the system dynamics are described by a function L(q, v, t) where q is position, v is velocity, and t is time. Together (q, v) make up the [phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) of the system. A particle at (1, 0) with velocity (2, 3) is considered to have a different instantaneous state than a particle at (1, 0) with velocity (-1, 5).

Comment: _State_. That is the product of past _states_, actions and interactions.

Comment: @causative: It's not like Lagrangians are the only formalism

Comment: @CriglCragl The other major one is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics which also uses phase space. In quantum physics too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics) Essentially any way you describe a system, you're going to need both position and velocity (or momentum) as functions of time describing the current state, because the evolution of the system over time depends on both.

Comment: @causative: They are both just reformulations of classical mechanics. They do not do anything new or unique, only make certain things about constraints more obvious. I fear you just want to use jargon here, that is not necessary. You could just say, property described by a function dependent on position & time, & convey the same (velocity is just the 1st partial derivative of position with respect to time). Can 'being an NBA player' be described by a mathematically compact function? I'd suggest 'no'.

Comment: @CriglCragl No, you can't let the state only be the position. Imagine the system is a ball at position (1, 0) under 9.8 m/s^2 of gravity. If that's all you give for the state, there is no way of telling where the ball is going to go next; it could go left, right, etc. You need to include the velocity or momentum in the state. Especially in Lagrangian or Hamiltonian dynamics, where you need to differentiate the Lagrangian or Hamiltonian with respect to momentum; this makes no sense if momentum is nothing more than mass times the derivative of position. Momentum has to be a separate variable.

Comment: Some authors call them diachronic properties, especially in linguistics, see e.g. [Epistemological and mathematical considerations on the structure of H-Semiotic Systems](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01969720290040740) and [Diachronic Mind, p. 194](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Diachronic_Mind/afR4S8u7HvkC).

Comment: @causative: Position *and time*. Sure in classical mechanics you need masses also, rather than generalised momentum - but that's just shorthand that gets super convenient at lightspeedish anyway. This isn't relevant to the question, so I'll stop.

Comment: @CriglCragl the "state" of a system needs to include all the information needed to determine its future states, except for external inputs or stochasticity. That means position and velocity (or, equivalently, position and momentum). Position by itself is not sufficient for that.

Comment: @CriglCragl and "time" is not a state variable, and is only necessary for systems whose equations of motion vary with time, which is not true for the ball in gravity mentioned earlier. Knowing the ball is initially at (1,0) and the initial time is 0 doesn't help you determine its future trajectory.

Comment: i am completely unsurprised that asking a simple question about terminology led to me getting 8 comments in which people gave me wrong answers, non-answers, or completely irrelevant lectures about physics. i hate philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about such a property. It is simply a property of objects that are associated with a state-function from Times→States. Take any person X with associated state-function F. Then X having your example property simply means that ∀t∈Times ( X is a child at time t ∧ ∃u∈Times ( t < u ∧ X is an NBA player at time u ) ), which can be expressed using F as ∀t∈Times ( Child(F(t)) ∧ ∃u∈Times ( t < u ∧ NBAPlayer(F(u)) ) ). This is no different from properties of real-world objects in general. I think you have unconsciously made the wrong assumption that an object has different properties over time in the *logical* sense of properties. Logically, if you wish to consider each object as lasting more than a single point in time, then it cannot have different properties over its lifespan. Each object would be associated with its *entire* lifespan, and we can of course define any property of objects based on that whole lifespan.

There are in fact *many* common such real-world properties, such as "dying" and "coming" and in general any present continuous participle or perfect participle in English. There are also special adjectives that capture more complicated such properties, such as "intermittent" and "consistent". There are special adverbs that modify adjectives to yield other complicated such properties, such as "temporarily" and "repeatedly". There is no obvious limit to the complexity of such properties in natural language. For example consider "temporarily intermittent".